# send data from linkedin Lead gen forms to Pardot or Sales Cloud

Tags: pardot

I have tried integrating LinkedIn lead gen forms to pardot via Zapier but the roadblock is that Zapier is updating prospect campaign if the prospect is already in the pardot system.

has anyone ever tried connecting LinkedIn lead gen forms to pardot without any tool or via API? any documentation would help.

Answer (score 1):

When I use Zapier to do this, I don't use the Pardot API endpoint, rather the Zapier Webhook where I POST to a Pardot Form Handler in kiosk mode.

This submission to a form "looks" right to sales when they view the Pardot activities - It's now a form. All the normal Pardot rules about existing campaigns are followed. And we can do Pardot Form Handler Completion actions easily so we don't need to do extra work trying to get these leads into SFDC with extra list, automation rules, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after doing some more research I figured that out :)